# Removing the tag for which a question was dupehammered

Tags: discussion, tags, editing, closed-questions, dupehammer

I noticed @cegaton had closed [this question as duplicate](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91748/sapling-tree-add-on-can-edit-the-trees-after-doing-something-else) using his gold [cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cycles) tag.  Just playing the "devil's advocate" I am in no way questioning @cegaton.

Consider some hypothetical question, which has been mis-tagged with [nothing-to-do-with-the-question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nothing-to-do-with-the-question)

The "issue of law" as I see it is, what if I edited, and removed the mis-tagged [nothing-to-do-with-the-question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nothing-to-do-with-the-question), because when searching by tag we don't want to come up with a result that has nothing to do with the tag,  the question couldn't then be closed by a user with a gold [nothing-to-do-with-the-question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nothing-to-do-with-the-question) tag.

What if it already had been?  I'd feel then that I'm questioning someone that knows more about [nothing-to-do-with-the-question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nothing-to-do-with-the-question) by removing the tag.

Comment: This question was a good example of editing out tags that have noting to to with the question...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Speaking just about the linked question, yes you absolutely could of edited out the cycles tag (I went and did it). That question has noting to do with any rendering, it is a modeling question.

Now when a question is closed as a dup, even when it was gold tag closed, you editing the question will not change that. (Except in some cases it will go through the [reopen review](https://blender.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/46175) because it was "Edited after being closed.")

In this instance the question being closed by someone that holds the gold close power makes no difference. **If a question has nothing to do with a tag, remove that tag.**

Comment: Still pretty off with the cycles stamp which is what I think was the main issue.